# Cannot see Nearby.ExposureNotification package

Tags: java, android

I have added the nearby package to build.gradle (module:app) as the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby'
```

However, I am trying to import the following package in my app but I cannot see it:

```
com.google.android.gms.nearby.exposurenotification
```

Here is the link for the package on google develoepr:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/exposurenotification/package-summary

If you look to this repo by google, you can see that they are using this package:
https://github.com/google/exposure-notifications-android
I explore the nearby.Nearby class in their project you can see that this class has a method called:

```
ExposureNotificationClient getExposureNotificationClient(Context c)
```

which I also don't see in the Nearby class of my application

I am implementing the last version of nearby package which is **17.0.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't see this package when implementing it from gradle. Because this package is an EAP ("early access program"). So you can copy this library and paste it to your application from the following link:
https://github.com/google/exposure-notifications-android/tree/master/app/libs

Also, have a look at this issue for more information:
https://github.com/google/exposure-notifications-android/issues/23